# Elasticsearch Phrase Suggester Context

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to use elastic search for spell checking and wondered if it is possible to use the phrase suggester with a context like what can be done with the completion method. I can't use the autocompletion method for this task as it doesn't work as a spell checker. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It always help to provide an example of what you've tried so far and why your current solution comes short.